# Crawling vs Indexing

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, google-search-console, local-seo

I am trying to do some SEO activites for my website [www.giftyourhubby.com](http://www.giftyourhubby.com)

When i looked into google search console. I found site is not indexed.

But i could list the site in google search.

What the reason for the same?

PS: I have recently submitted sitemap and its still indexing and its just 50% indexed

[image: Crawl status]
[image: Index Status]

Comment: Google Search Console is notoriously slow and some metrics will not begin to reflect reality for as long as a month. So if this is all new, and it sounds like it is, you should not panic. It will all work out in time. Be patient.

Comment: Make sure that you add all the possible properties, just in case, to make Google and you are in agreement. Add HTTP www and non-www as well as HTTPS www and non-www. Check all of these. If there should be nothing in the metrics, then do not worry that you do not see anything. However, sometimes, Google is indexing a site one way and not another. Adding the properties will allow you to know this. Cheers!!

Comment: BTW- You will want to only have www or non-www. If your site is available via both, then Google is likely indexing the one you do not have a property set-up for. ;-) You should redirect one to the other once you decided which one you want. After that, then indexing will show up for that property.

Answer (score 1):

Any numbers it gives you will be imprecise. This is very much by design! The search console often has 'fuzzed' numbers and doesn't update immediately. There's a 2-3 day lag on things like search analytics.

Use it for guidance only. In this case, once it says you've got some pages indexed you can at least be sure it's indexed something. But just because it says '0' doesn't mean it hasn't indexed something in the past few days.

Comment: Index Status is always very accurate. It just takes a while for Google to collect the metrics for new sites and new properties. It can take about a month. After that, Index Status should be spot on. Updated daily.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the 'Index status' is reporting fairly accurate numbers. Especially when taking into account that a 'site:www.giftyourhubby.com' query on Google also returns zero results, I would say that we can be pretty certain that your site indeed isn't indexed at the moment.

Have you received any messages from Google stating a reason for this? When I crawl/analyze your website it isn't showing any red flags in terms of not-getting-indexed (meta noindex, robots.txt, overly weird technical setup stuff, etc.).

Have you perhaps used another setup (for instance https, or without www) in the past? Or is there any reason to assume this domain has received a severe Google penalty recently?

Comment: But if you remove www its works  'site:giftyourhubby.com'

Comment: It seems that both giftyourhubby.com and www.giftyourhubby.com can be reached, but only the www is added to webmaster central. When you redirect the non-www to the www or vice-versa then the Index status will show the right number (and some other SEO issues will be fixed).